# Fortran syntax highlighting in listings

Tags: listings, formatting, color, highlighting, code

I've got some Fortran 90 source code I want to put into my thesis appendix. For this I'm using the `listings` package. Is it possible to have colored syntax highlighting for the Fortran code?

Comment: `listings` should recognise Fortran as one of the known languages: what did you try?

Comment: I found a good solution: use the 'minted' package. This appears to be the best way to auto-color-highlight syntax in code listings. http://code.google.com/p/minted/

Comment: Yeah but it doesn't colour the syntax at all

Comment: You can find minted in the list of my link [several alternative packages for syntax highlighting](http://www.ctan.org/keyword/computer_code). And there are at least two more packages using the Pygments library: [verbments](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/verbments) and [texments](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/texments).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to set the language and the kind of highlighting, e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=[90]Fortran,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle=\color{red},
  commentstyle=\color{green},
  morecomment=[l]{!\ }% Comment only with space after !
}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
! Der folgende Fortran-Code ist bei Wikipedia geklaut.
SUBROUTINE test( Argument1, Argument2, Argument3 )
   REAL,              INTENT(IN) :: Argument1
   CHARACTER(LEN= *), INTENT(IN) :: Argument2
   INTEGER,           INTENT(IN), OPTIONAL :: Argument3
   ! This makes sense
END SUBROUTINE
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

For more information about the used settings with `\lstset` see the manual of [listings](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) package.

BTW: There are [several alternative packages for syntax highlighting](https://www.ctan.org/topic/listing). With [fortran](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fortran) there seems to be even a package to print Fortran programs. But I've never used this, it cannot be used for syntax highlighting and was made to be used with plainTeX. So maybe if you want to try an alternative, e.g., [highlight](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/highlight) would be ab better suggestion.